# iText PDFWriter - Writing table header if the few table rows go to new page

Tags: itext

I am using `PdfWriter` to create a PDF document. I am adding a `PdfPTable` to the PDF document. This table has header row and then actual data rows. If the table is big, then part of it gets carried forward to new page. I want this page to have table header row as well. However, I want this header row only when the table data goes on new page.

Comment: I never received any feedback on my answer. Didn't it solve your problem?

Answer (score 7):

This is how you create a table with a header row:

```
// table with 2 columns:
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
// header row:
table.addCell("Key");
table.addCell("Value");
table.setHeaderRows(1);
// many data rows:
for (int i = 1; i < 51; i++) {
    table.addCell("key: " + i);
    table.addCell("value: " + i);
}
document.add(table);
```

In this case, the table needs more than one page. As you used `setHeaderRows()` with `1` as parameter, the first row will be repeated:

[image: Screen shot]

If you don't want the header to be present on the first page, you have to add a single line: `table.setSkipFirstHeader(true);`

```
// table with 2 columns:
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
// header row:
table.addCell("Key");
table.addCell("Value");
table.setHeaderRows(1);
table.setSkipFirstHeader(true);
// many data rows:
for (int i = 1; i < 51; i++) {
    table.addCell("key: " + i);
    table.addCell("value: " + i);
}
document.add(table);
```

Now the table looks like this:

[image]